# What seasonal vegetable side dishes are appropriate for Hungarian Goulash?

Tags: vegetables, pairing

We are planning a traditional Hungarian Goulash dinner, and apart from egg noodles, would like a vegetable side-dish to accompany. It's late October, and we'd prefer some seasonal ingredients if possible. What vegetable side dishes compliment a hearty, flavorful stew like goulash?

Comment: "Seasonal" obviously depends on your location, and when your question happens to get read. Please be specific. Even then, this reads somewhat like a poll to me as "compliment" could mean just about anything, especially if we don't know what's in the goulash.

Comment: @Aaronut, I'm puzzled about how much more specific you want the OP to get. He said "late October". Does he really need to specify "northern hemisphere"?

Comment: @Marti, are you serious? Even if the climates were the same everywhere, the species aren't. Canada's seasonal vegetables are not the same as Hungary's.

Comment: @Aaronut: actually, for most vegetables, it's close enough, especially with modern grocery stores. I mean, OK, if the OP was somewhere in inland China or something, the veggies might be very different, but then he probably wouldn't be making goulash, because the available *meats* would be very different, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sweet and sour red cabbage,  cuts through the richness of the goulash very nicely - particularly if you cook some thin slices of tart apples with the cabbage. The vinegar also turns the cabbage vivid purple which also adds a nice contrast to earthy goulash.  I found this recipe that is almost identical to my mom's (although I probably would opt out of using the clove):

http://m.allrecipes.com/recipe/139977/recipegrandma-jeanettes-amazing-german-red-cabbage

Comment: Three great answers, but we went with a sweet-and-sour red cabbage dish, so you get the checkmark.

Comment: @RISwampYankee, thanks! Hope your meal was yummy!

Answer (score 7):

[Possibly irrelevant-to-you aside: a true *Hungarian* goulash (as opposed to a North American or German or what-have-you goulash) is a soup. It includes a few root vegetables and possibly some "pinched noodles" (tiny little egg+flour dumplings) in the soup itself, but it is served with a hearty slice of bread or two, nothing more. So in that sense, the answer to your question is "mu".]

If what you're actually making is a meat stew with paprika (what in Hungarian would be called *pörkölt*), then the traditional accompaniments are either potatoes (with beef) or spaetzle (with any type of meat), and some sort of vinegary vegetable salad — either a cucumber salad, or some other vegetable dressed the same way as a cucumber salad (tomatoes, peppers), or pickled vegetables (sauerkraut-stuffed peppers, gherkins, that sort of thing). Another possibility is red cabbage, which (unlike cucumbers) is at least starting to be seasonal at the end of October.

Comment: Yup, even tho the recipe says goulash, it's probably better described as a beef pörkölt, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

What's in season now are root vegetables, squashes, and some greens and cabbages. You'll need something that can stand up to or compliment a rich dish like goulash, how about roasted beets with sour cream, which would tie into the sour cream in the goulash? It's such a simple dish: roast your beets skin-on (or steam them), let them cool enough then peel with your fingers, then cut them up and mix them up with sea salt and a bit of sour cream. Simple, easy, and really tasty.

Alternatively you could make some red or green cabbage, brussel sprouts pan-fried (after partially steaming them) with some slivered almonds, or if you can find them steamed brussel sprout tops (the leaves on the top of the stalk) sliced up with a bit of butter.